# how to insert objects to NSMutable Array from a NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have a NSDictionary with two arrays like this

```
questionAndAnswer= [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:answerList forKey:questionList];
```

there are two answerList objects for particular question(key). that part is OK (dictionary is populate correctly)

I want to insert answers to a new array called chckList with respect to selected question. I tried like this

```
NSString *selectedQuestion=[questionList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[self.checkList insertObject:[questionAndAnswer objectForKey:selectedQuestion] atIndex:0];
```

But it fires an exception, what's wrong in my code?

Comment: You care calling **objectForKey** in a UIDeviceRGBColor object and not on a dictionary, check your variables.

Comment: https://skitch.com/mauricio-linhares/fwwbi/java-how-can-i-read-a-file-to-an-inputstream-then-write-it-into-an-outputstream-in-scala-stack-overflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should actually do (note the plurals in the method name):

```
questionAndAnswer= [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:answerList forKeys:questionList];
```

What you posted used one array as key for another. The above uses the items in one array as keys for the other array. Big difference.

But the error message you get "sounds" very much like an uninitialized or already dealloced and "re-used" variable. So:

- look if the `questionAndAnswer` you query is the same as the one you created;
- look if it was released or auto-released already. The `dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:` convenience method returns an auto-released object, and you should take care of retaining it before the autorelease pool can release it. Use a `@property (retain)` and `@synthesize` it to store it.

Comment: @sajaz: could you show how you retain `questionAndAnswer` between method calls (usually you do `self.questionAndAnswer = ...`)?

Comment: I'm quite new to stack Overflow, really sorry for that. I'm not retaining questionAndAnswer. I just use like this in header class. @property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *questionAndAnswer; what you mean by "retain" I have no idea, please tell me

Comment: @sajaz: If you don't know what `retain` is, you probably use ARC. <g> Fact is that what you think is an NSDictionary turns out to be an UIDeviceRGBColor. Go and debug your code to find out how that can happen. In the mean time, don't use `questionAndAnswer`, use `self.questionAndAnswer` everywhere and see if that helps.